# CSS change custom cursor image origin (hotspot) to center

Tags: css, custom-cursor

I want to use a custom image for a cursor.

This is fine, but from what I can see - the origin (tip of arrow) is by default at the top-left point of my image.

How can I set the origin to be the center of my image.

Here is a demo snippet to demonstrate the problem

```css
div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  cursor: url(http://placehold.it/50x30), auto
}
```

```html
<div>the cat in the hat<br> the cat in the hat<br> the cat in the hat<br> the cat in the hat</div>
```

Notice that when I try to select the text - it selects from the top-left of the image.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

One solution would be to move the position of your image to match the mouse pointer

```
cursor: url(image) [x y|auto];
```

Doesn't respond to the question but this is working

**HTML**

```
div
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    background: pink;
    cursor: url(http://placehold.it/50x30) 25 15, auto;
}
```

Comment: Chrome/Chromium has a terrible bug from version 25 to 41, the CSS3 cursor position is broken: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28372383/1176454

Answer (score 26):

You can set it by:

```
cursor:url(http://placehold.it/50x30) 25 15, auto;
```

The two parameters I added set the center of your cursor.

Answer (score 8):

I just found this from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/cursor/url):

> Support for the CSS 3 syntax for cursor values got added in Gecko 1.8
>   (Firefox 1.5):
>
> cursor:  [ [`<x> <y>`]?,]* keyword It allows specifying the
>   coordinates of the cursor's hotspot, which will be clamped to the
>   boundaries of the cursor image. If none are specified, the coordinates
>   of the hotspot are read from the file itself (for CUR and XBM files)
>   or are set to the top left corner of the image. An example of the CSS3
>   syntax is:

```
.foo  {
    cursor:  auto;
    cursor:  url(cursor1.png) 4 12, auto;
}

.bar  {
    cursor:  pointer;
    cursor:  url(cursor2.png) 2 2, pointer;
}
```

> /* fallsback onto 'auto' and 'pointer' in IE, but must be set
>   separately */ **The first number is the x-coordinate, and the second
>   number is the y-coordinate. The example will set the hotspot to be the
>   pixel at (4,12) from the top left (0,0).**