# Cursor point to left bottom corner

Tags: css

```
div{
    width:200px; height:200px; background:red;
    cursor:url(images/eyedropper.png) 25 25, auto;
}


<div></div>
```

[image]

I have an eyedropper image for cursor like above

my problem is this image point to left bottom corner, but cursor default is point to left top corner. Is any way to change pointer to left bottom or move background image?

Comment: you can change its direction in photoshop if it is not that neccesary

Comment: looks very weird if i point to left top

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS change custom cursor image origin (hotspot) to center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560878/css-change-custom-cursor-image-origin-hotspot-to-center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change its direction in photoshop if it is not that neccesary 
if you want to change direction use transform rotate and set deg according to your need

```
  div{
        width:200px; height:200px; background:red;
        position:relative;
    }
.cursor{ position:absolute;cursor:url(images/eyedropper.png) 25 25, auto;
            transform: rotate(90deg);}

<div> <div class="cursor"></div></div>
```

Comment: transform will rotate all my content inside of div :(

Comment: try to make cursor in another div and put it absolute

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this via CSS is the resize property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

If I understood you right, you would have to add

```
nw-resize;
```

to your cursor selector. You can try all of the said resize functions to get your desired effect.