# HTML Input cursor position issue in Chrome when value is empty

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-input

Just recently I have noticed out text inputs having a display issue in Google Chrome but only when the text is empty.

Notice how in the top image, when the input is empty, the cursor is too high within the text input.

[image: Cursor issue in Chrome]

But once we type some text it corrects itself:

[image: Password input]

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efgq1svz/)** to illustrate. May require Google Chrome version: 38.0.2125.101 m

HTML:

```
<input name="tb_password" type="password" id="tb_password" class=" validate[required,custom[password]]" placeholder="Type your password here" autocomplete="off" style="
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 46px;
">
```

CSS:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
width: 100%;
height: 46px;
line-height: 46px;
font-size: 11pt;
color: #555 !important;
text-indent: 15px;
border-top: solid 1px #c5c5c5;
border-left: solid 1px #c5c5c5;
border-bottom: solid 1px #dadada;
border-right: solid 1px #dadada;
background: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

Comment: weird... i have same problem here, i think it is a chrome bug

Comment: look this http://codepen.io/leandroruel/pen/yjopx

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a bug in Chrome 38.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in the latest Chrome Canary 40.

Comment: Could this be a regression of this bug? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47284

Comment: same here. Got the same problem. I thought it's just my website, but all the sites I visit have the same bug. Haha! :D

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Cause:

Looks like this is a regression bug in the Chromium 38 engine. I can reproduce in Chrome 38.* and Opera 25.* (which uses Chromium 38).

### Reported Bug/s:

As pointed out by @JackieChiles it appears to be a regression of this [closed as obselete] bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47284

**As suggested in the closed bug, I have logged a new one. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426802&thanks=426802&ts=1414143535**

And have also referenced another reported bug which appears to highlight the same bug, yet fails to define the exact issue in a generic way.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=394664

### Workaround:

As detailed in other answers above the workaround is to avoid using a pixel-based `line-height` attribute. For example swapping `line-height:50px` to `line-height:1em` or `line-height:100%` will yield more expected behaviour.

Comment: Set height to what you want (e.g. 50px) and line-height to 100% 
http://jsfiddle.net/zxa8d0h7/1/

Comment: That is what the answer says

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong.  I clarified a point and added a fiddle (and even up voted your answer).

Comment: @yar1 Hey yeah thanks it's cool I was just confused because I thought you were basically saying the same thing I was in the answer! Yours is more to the point mind =)

Comment: This solution had no positive effect on Chrome for me

Comment: Could be related: Chrome/Chromium has a terrible bug from version 25 to 41, the CSS3 cursor position is broken: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28372383/1176454

Answer (score 8):

Adding `line-height:100%`seems to fix the issue for us:

http://jsfiddle.net/ddjj9wxc/

Comment: I wonder if this is correct behaviour? I would have thought line-height:100% would have inherited from the inputs parent?

Comment: @Le-roy It may have something to do with the display property of the element. For inline elements, you are right, line-height seems to be inherited from the closest block parent, but for elements with display:block or inline-block (also floated elements) line-height effects the element itself. In this case I think it works because in chrome default display value for input elements is inline-block. I currently have the above rule applied just in webkit to avoid any problems with older browsers.

Comment: This worked for me, while the accepted answer didn't

Comment: @321zeno I'm a little confused.. the accepted answer says add "line-height:100%" how did that not work for you yet this same answer did! Actually the accepted answer lists *two* options but yeah.

Comment: @Le-roy your answer has a some edits, I assume it was different at the time I read it

Answer (score 6):

i suggest don't use `line-height` at all, it may not be the proper answer but its working for me (latest chrome)

**Updated fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/efgq1svz/11/

Comment: Interesting. Your Fiddle isn't working for me. I wonder how that could happen?

Comment: *try this pen** [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tkyzu], i don't know why?? but it still working

Comment: The solution above has the same problem for me too unfortunately.

Comment: OK, the cursor position problem still exists in the jsfiddle example because there is an inline line-height left in the HTML. If you remove that, the cursor position will look good. It looks like Chrome centers the text and cursor without any additional line-height or padding setting in the latest release.

Comment: I still suggest that you remove the inline line-height styling in your fiddle, then it will look correct and @Le-roy can mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the CSS style on the text input from `line-height: 46px` to `line-height: 1em` resolves the issue; however I am uncertain as to why.

Comment: if you do it, the placeholder go to down

Answer (score 0):

There is another hack that no one have mentioned as I can see. You could use a @media query to check out Chrome:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
    line-height: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar issue. But I found it's better to use number for `line-height` instead of length(px, em or rem). Maybe using following code fix this problem:

```
input[type="text"] {
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
```

Plus, maybe the css above need to be paired with `-webkit-appaearance: none` for the desired rendering effect. Anyway, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In 2012, I made an HTML5 canvas web app and used a CSS3 property to change the cursor position when using an image as cursor:

`#canvas {
    cursor: url(../image/pen_red_ff0000.gif)0 20, auto;
}`

It worked for months when developing my project on Firefox, Chrome/Chromium and other browsers but since at least Chrome 38, the cursor position change was ignored. I'm using the Chromium Ubuntu version and today, I've updated to Chromium 40 and the bug is still here even after reboot and deleting ".config/chromium".

The version from Ubuntu packages is "Version 40.0.2214.94 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)" but a few days ago I tried the latest official Chromium Linux "Version 42.0.2287.0 (64-bit)" from https://download-chromium.appspot.com/ and the bug did not appear.

My web app is here http://drawcode.eu/projects/connect-points/, you have to connect points but on Chromium from Ubuntu, I have to click 20 pixels under the middle of the points. It's a cursor position issue so I think my problem is related to this thread.

Can someone confirm having the bug and know since when it's really fixed?
Note that the latest official Chromium I've downloaded is version 42 (not stable). My Chromium 40 from Ubuntu still has the bug but @Salmonface said it was fixed in version 40 [HTML Input cursor position issue in Chrome when value is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270582/html-input-cursor-position-issue-in-chrome-when-value-is-empty/28372383#comment41388146_26270582)

Edit: On Debian, I had this bug with Chromium 37 (not 38) too! The bug is still here on Chrome beta (version 41). Here is a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/baptx/L0fmvs7a/

Edit 2: In fact the CSS3 cursor position bug appeared in Chromium 25 (https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/171003/) and it seems fixed in Chromium 42 (https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/313000/), you can try by yourself my HTML5 canvas app and see that the CSS3 cursor position is wrong. From Chromium 25 to Chromium 36 (tested with developer build 261001), the Fiddle I shared works but the browser allows you to select text on a div with a good or wrong cursor position. From Chromium 37 (tested with developer build 271001) to Chromium 41, you can't select text with the good cursor position on the Fiddle.

The bug is not GNU/Linux platform only, it also appears on a Windows 8 virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue those days but only on IOS 8.1, so maybe my solution will help somebody. The issue came from a div tag which had set a transform CSS property. I solve the problem with the following code:

```
#your-parent-div {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
}
```