# Text field indicator off-place only in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, textfield

I'm facing an odd problem since the last update on Chrome.

I have a search field that is triggered by clicking a search button and once clicked the text field becomes focused via jQuery.

Before the recent update on Chrome everything was peachy but now the bleeping text indicator appears on the top of the container instead where it's supposed to be, this happens only in Chrome since the last update.

Have a look at the photo attached to see what I'm talking about.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/deWmJ.jpg - On Chrome

https://i.stack.imgur.com/io316.jpg - How is it supposed to look (and looked before the update) on Firefox

PS. I need 10 "Reputation Points" to post an image?

```css
#mt-search-top-overlay {
  z-index: 101;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(39, 39, 39, .90);
}
#header .container {
  position: relative;
}
.searchform {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.mt-search-top-close {
  float: right;
  color: #999;
  margin: 17px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
#mt-search-top-overlay p {
  padding: 0 42px 0 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#mt-search-top-overlay input[type=text] {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
#mt-search-top-overlay input[type=text]:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mt-search-top-overlay" style="display: block;">
  <div class="container">
    <form method="get" class="searchform clearfix">
      <div class="mt-search-top-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </div>
      <p>
        <input type="text" class="searchfield nooutline" name="s" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search...">
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide code, not a screen shot of some parts of it... you don't need reputation to create a proper question...

Comment: could you maybe provide the computed css style for that text field?

Comment: Sorry for that since the chrome developer tool was open in the screenshot and the element was selected with the CSS displayed to the right it's enough but it clearly wasn't so I went on and added all the associated HTML and CSS for the field.

Comment: Ive been seeing that too on pages Ive built that at one point didn't have that issue. Maybe it's something buggy in a recent release?

Comment: @Brian I can confirm that it worked a week or so ago before the latest update of Google Chrome and I'm relieved it's not only me.

Comment: This is a bug in Chrome version 38: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26270582/830125

Comment: @JackieChiles Thank you for that, I tried searching before I posted but I didn't know the proper term for the darn thing "Input Cursor" hhh and I typed "Bleeping Text Field Indicator" hhh

Comment: Could be a regression of this bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem with latest Google Chrome, and I solved setting `line-height` value to `1` or `normal`.