# line-height on input fields messed up on chrome 38 on my previous websites recently

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Did they change anything recently on chrome?

Some of the websites I've made before seemed to have a messed up line-height on input fields

[image]

The text entered seemed to be ok, only the blinking line.

It was perfectly aligned before when I've published it not too long ago. And it only happens in chrome.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It'd be more helpful if we could see the code and/or a demo in codepen or jsfiddle. Otherwise, it will be very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks css or is this your own?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270582/html-input-cursor-position-issue-in-chrome-when-value-is-empty - it's a bug in Chrome 38 and is fixed in 40

Comment: @Christina Thank you very much. It did indeed solve the problem.

Comment: Good. I just noticed in Bootstrap, they're trying to correct an IOS bug with input dates and have to use a line-height on their inputs and now it's effing up, less noticeable with placeholder text but still. It wasn't an issue last week with 37, seriously Firefox is more stable these days.